# ode and area of triangle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Question: find a curve $x$ so that the area bounded between it's tangent at some point $t$ and the time axis on the interval between the point of contact of $x$ and it's tangent ( $t$ ), and the contact point of the tangent with time axis is constant.
I tried to denote $b = - \frac{x_0}{\dot{x}}$ as the contact point of the tangent with time and to reach an expression for $x$ from the relation $\frac{|t-b|\cdot |x|}{2} = a^2$ (the area must be positive) but I get nowhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define a time $t_0$ and calculate the tangent $T$ at $t_0$. We know its slope $m = \dot{x}(t_0)$. Additionally the point ($t_0, x(t_0$)) has to be on it. So we can calculate the $x$-axis intercept to be $q = x(t_0) - \dot{x}(t_0)t_0$. Now we can calculate the $t$-axis intercept:
$$
0 = \dot{x}(t_0)t + x(t_0) - \dot{x}(t_0)t_0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad t = t_0 - \frac{x(t_0)}{\dot{x}(t_0)}
$$
The length of the basis of the triangular area (on the $t$-axis) we can compute to be $a = t_0 - (t_0 - \frac{x(t_0)}{\dot{x}(t_0)}) = \frac{x(t_0)}{\dot{x}(t_0)}$. The height of this triangle is already known to be $x(t_0)$. Therefore the area has to be $A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{x(t_0)}{\dot{x}(t_0)} \cdot x(t_0) = \frac{x^2(t_0)}{2\dot{x}(t_0)} = Const$.

This has to be true for all $t_0$, so you get your differential equation
$$
\dot{x} = \frac{x^2}{2C},
$$
which you can solve normally.